# Read email messages from Android app

Tags: java, android, email

Is it possible to read email message from any mail inbox in Android application without relying on accounts configured in Email application and without relying on any Android intent?

If that is possible, how to do it (either via IMAP or POP3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/ port of javamail which does IMAP and MIME so far.

Comment: I suppose any example of how to read email message using JavaMail could be used as base for code using JavaMail port. Right?

Comment: correct, they pretty much just extracted the JavaMail source from J2EE