# pop3 in Android

Tags: java, android, email

How can I use POP3 for to read the letters in Android with POP3 or IMAP?

Guide me, maybe can I use some libraries and other? I must to read some letters in my app.

Thanks, Roman Sytnik.

Comment: Try searching first next time. This is a common question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140939/read-email-messages-from-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javamail-Android project should help:
https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/

Answer (score 0):

[Chilkat](http://www.example-code.com/android/pop3_http_proxy.asp) has an Android library that you could use.